# Proving a metric on X.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be the collection of all sequences of positive integers. If $x=(n_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ and $y=(m_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ are two elements of $X$, set

$$k(x,y)=\inf\{j:n_j\neq m_j\}$$ and

$$d(x,y)= \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x=y$} \\ \frac{1}{k(x,y)} & \text{if $x \neq y$} \end{cases}$$

Prove that $d$ is a metric on $X$.

I am wondering if my procedure for this problem is correct thus far. Also, I am having trouble proving the triangle inequality. We know that a metric space has the following properties:

1. $d(x,y) \geq 0$
2. $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x=y$
3. $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$
4. $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$

I have the following so far:

1. If $x=y$, this is trivial, since $d(x,y)=0$ in this case. If $x \neq y$, $d(x,y)=\frac{1}{k(x,y)}$, where $k(x,y) \geq 1$. Therefore, $d(x,y) \geq 0$
2. This is true by definition. (Otherwise, I am not sure how else to formally prove this fact)
3. If $x=y$, $d(x,y)=0=d(y,x)$. If $x \neq y$, $d(x,y)=\frac{1}{k(x,y)}$ (Not sure how to progress here. Do I just assume that $\frac{1}{k(x,y)}=\frac{1}{k(y,x)}$?)
4. Don't know how to start here. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties 1., 2. and 3. are proved correctly - for 3. one can say that $k(x,y)=k(y,x)$ by the
definition of $k(x,y)$.

4. Let $z=(l_j)_{j=1}^{\infty}$. If $x=y$, then 
   $$d(x,y)=0\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y).$$ 
   Also, if $x=z$, then 
   $$d(x,y)=0+d(x,y)=0+d(z,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y).$$
   Similarly, we consider the case $y=z$.
   Assume therefore that $x, y, z$ are pairwise distinct sequences. Let $k(x,y)=p$, $k(x,z)=q$ and $k(z,y)=r$.
   If both $q$ and $r$ were strictly larger than $p$, then $l_p=n_p$ and $l_p=m_p$. 
   But this is impossible because $n_p\ne m_p$ (note that $p$ is the smallest index such 
   that $n_p\ne m_p$). Hence $q \leq p$ or $r\leq p$ or, equivalently, $\frac{1}{p}\leq \frac{1}{q}$ or $\frac{1}{p}\leq \frac{1}{r}$. But this gives
   $$ d(x,y)=\frac{1}{p} \leq \frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}=d(x,z)+d(z,y). $$